# Custom taxonomy template for custom fields loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, templates

I have jobs custom post type
which contains custom taxonomies

- Location
- Company
- State
- Qualification

and added custom fields

- Name of company - text field
- Post Name - text field
- Number of posts - number field
- qualification - text field
- Last Date - text field more
- details - text field(Post link)

now how can i add these custom fields of custom post type in a custom taxonomy template.

In custom taxonomy template these fields should be displayed in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the exact query is but these fields can be accessed on the taxonomy template in the same way as they are accessed elsewhere - using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

The code in your taxonomy template has a part which loops through all the relevant posts and gives back the info. You can sort the post ID from it and use it in `get_post_meta()`

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for.

**EDIT (Code Added)**

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            echo $company_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name-of-company', true );

        endwhile;
    endif;
```

Comment: sid@ can you please give me template code

Comment: It will be tough without knowing how your taxonomy template is structured. I still have edited my answer to add a basic structure of code. See it it helps

Comment: thanks sid, but i want to display custom fields loop in table in archive template like this [link[(https://imgur.com/a/Lsyqj)

Comment: yes. Using the code in my answer you could populate all the custom fields associated with a post. You can add the table styling as you like with it.